# Deploy angular 2 in iis

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2015

I'm using angular 2 in MVC and web api. I need to deploy the application to iis.. when i tried to publish project into iis location. MVC API is working but angular not working. I have tried to build the app in Angular/cli but i'm getting ng not recognised error. But any other way to build the application.

Comment: Next time... Plz read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Which errors did you get when opening the angular app? Etc. Pp

Comment: ng not recognized.. even i have added the enviroment variable %Path%.

Comment: plz post some content from the develeoper console, images, etc...stacktraces, (fine formatted)